# How to enable free monitoring in mongodb if access control is enabled?

Tags: mongodb

I want to enable free monitoring on my MongoDB standalone instance running on AWS. I had performed before enabling access control. After enabling, when I tried

```
db.enableFreeMonitoring()
```

it returns following error.

> uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
> "ok" : 0,
> "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { setFreeMonitoring: 1.0, action: "enable", lsid: { id: UUID("0483e6c8-4d96-4eae-9967-608838f07f42") }, $db: "admin" }",
> "code" : 13,
> "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
> } :

As per the documentation, I have granted the admin `clusterMonitor` role. Still same error. Is there any other way?

Comment: check `db.connectionStatus()` to check the current roles.

Comment: @Joe TypeError: db.connectionStatus is not a function

Comment: apologies, that is a command that should be run like `db.runCommand("connectionStatus")`

Comment: @Joe, thanks. It shows that clusterMonitor role is applied.  "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "clusterMonitor",
                                "db" : "admin"
                        },

Comment: Did you use the required command line option or configuration setting mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I enabled monitoring by giving the user the role *root*

```
use admin;
db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }]);
```

You may want to think this through before assigning the user with 'root' privileges.
I believe dbOwner and adminUser roles could also accomplish the same task, although I have not tried them.
Here's the link to the documentation [Role-Aased Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/index.html#superuser-roles)

Comment: `root` shouldn't be required, as per [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.enableFreeMonitoring/#access-control), which state that the `clusterMonitor` role should provide sufficient permissions.